# Simplest way to use NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Can I use **NSTableView** like I've used **ListView** in Windows? By that I mean *JUST* adding rows to the view.

I need to display a very simple two columned table and I don't want to write all this data related crap. Can I just 'add' stuff to a table view?

If not what is the simplest way to do what I'm trying to do (preferably without data sources)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Cocoa works much differently than windows common controls.

Since Cocoa uses the MVC pattern, you will need to familiarize yourself with it.

In windows a ListView is usually a Model Controller and View all-in-one, not so with Cocoa.

Take the time to learn the platform, don't try to program like you are still programming for windows. You will struggle harder trying to avoid learning than you will just learning to begin with.

See also: [Add/remove rows to/from NSTableView in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306737/add-remove-rows-to-from-nstableview-in-objective-c)